# Create SOAP request with element attribute using Zend_Soap_Client and stdObject

Tags: php, zend-soap

I'm calling a service witch among many other parameters demands an entry like (Taken from soapUI):

> ```
>   <v110:ReadWorkerRequest>
>      <v111:Key v111:type="INITIALS">RKM</v111:Key>
>   </v110:ReadWorkerRequest>
> ```

How do I get the Zend_Soap_Client to send the type-attribute in the Key element?

As this is just part of a rather big service, I've been creating classes to create the datastructure, like:

```
class Key {
  public $_ = 'RKM;
  public $type = 'INITIALS';
}

class Body {
  public $ReadWorkerRequest;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->ReadWorkerRequest = new Key();
  }
}
```

However, I do not even get to sending the request as PHP fails, telling me: "SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'Key' property"

So my question is, how do I create an object structure, possibly with a subpart created as an Array which will honor this?

Or is the object structure correct, and I need to use classmap or SoapVar (I tried some combinations, but not with any success)

Happy holidays, for those of you who has them! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have spent many hours myself trying to solve this problem but the best I could come up with was to use the XSD_ANYXML hack, eg:

```
$this->ReadWorkerRequest = new SoapVar( '<v111:Key v111:type="INITIALS">RKM</v111:Key>', XSD_ANYXML );
```

Its a pretty nasty hack though. Hopefully somebody else can provide a better solution.